# How to test Ruby OCI8 database services

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing, oci8

Are there any tutorials or examples of testing Ruby OCI8 database services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "C:\RubyXXX\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\ruby-oci8-2.1.0-x86-mingw32\test\test_oci8.rb" or wherever it is on your drive.

Lots of weblinks i'm not going to include, you can google them yourselve.

A very simple example

```
require 'oci8'

oci = OCI8.new('schema','password','db.server')
oci.exec('select * from table') do |record|
  puts record.join(',')
end
```

Some unit testing for active-record and sqlite, you can adapt this for oci8

```
require 'active_record'
require "test/unit"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database  => "sample.db"
)
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base;end

class Tester < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_title
    assert_equal('Sticky Fingers', Album.find_by_title('Sticky Fingers').title)
  end
end
```

Comment: Mr Peter : Here question is not like how to connect oci8 in ruby.
The question is how we can write unit test cases for a ruby scirpt where oci8 services have been used.
See links below to get an idea for the same. It showed a simple example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing_frameworks_for_Ruby
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing

Comment: i can't check here, no oracle nor oci8 installed but i believe the file i mention in my answer has some unit-testing, i added an example of how i do my testing, it's with ORM active-record and database sqlite but you will see what i mean

Comment: i upvoted your question but someone else downvoted, i believe you 'd better explain better what you want by editing your question

Comment: I was able to write the test cases using rsync thanks all for your inputs :)

Comment: you're welcome, but could you please accent my answer and perhaps even upvote it :)

Comment: @peterSmith I dont have reputation for upvote but I accepted you answer.
Thanks